# How to inject service in DTO class? (NestJS)

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

How to inject service in DTO class?
I have DTO and Service
dto

```js
@Injectable()
export class DTO {
  constructor(private readonly testService: TestService) {}

  @Validate(IsValidAddress)
  address: string;

  @Expose()
  get realAddress() {
    return this.testService.isValidAddress(this.address);
  }
}
```

and dto used in addressController

```js
@Controller('address')
export class AddressController {
  constructor(private readonly addressService: AddressService) {}

  @Get('balance')
  getBalance(@Param() params: DTO) {
    console.log(params.realAddress);
    return this.addressService.getBalance({ ...params });
  }
}
```

this throw error that testService undefined..
How can i use that service in dto class?

Comment: Have you actually imported your TestService?

Comment: Yes I import TestService in AddressModule

Comment: Your testservice is used in the dto class. You need an import statement there too.

Comment: It's been almost 4 years. Have you found the solution for this? @SeungJun